# Energy and mass at absolute zero temperature

Tags: special-relativity, energy, mass, temperature, mass-energy

Hi my question is if the temperature of a particle is reduced to absolute zero the that particle has lost its energy so it has no movement. Particles have mass and Einstein said mass equates to energy. Particles have mass so at absolute zero the have no energy does this mean that particles at zero energy have no mass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. At absolute zero particles lose their kinetic energy but not their mass-energy. They still have mass.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89181/discussion-on-answer-by-g-smith-energy-and-mass-at-absolute-zero-temperature).

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is momentum or mass, absolute zero cannot be reached. e^2 = (mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2. If any mass exists, there is still energy.